# Finding number of processes created

Tags: operating-system

**Find the number of new processes created.**

```
void main() {
    int i;
    A for(i=0;i<2;i++) {
    B fork();
    C   if(!fork()) {
    D       execl(“/bin/ls”,”ls”,NULL);
    E       fork();
        }
    F   fork();
      }
    G   fork();
      }
```

> Ans: 41 Please explain me how to reach this answer.

Comment: Will you do my homework in return?

Comment: The intention of `Please explain me how to reach this answer` will leave you of no-where!!! Please try to learn. SO and other sites are best forum cum tutorial. Explain what you thought off and where are you facing problem!